# in_array() is not working while calling php script in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I have called core php function from controller of Yii2 in that in_array() function is not working but I have called individually then it is working.
following is my array which I have passed searchForId().

```
 Array
 (
   [1] => Array
     (
        [2] => PRICE:
     )

   [4] => Array
    (
        [1] => S/NO
        [3] => INSULATED TANK SIZE
        [7] => QTY
        [8] => U.PRICE(Qr.)
        [10] => TOTAL PRICE (Qr.)
    )

  [5] => Array
    (
        [1] => 01
        [3] => FZ 198(S) (11 x 6 x 3MH)
w/p (3+3)
        [7] => 1 SET
        [8] => 390,197.00
        [10] => 390,197.00
    )

  [6] => Array
    (
        [1] => 02
        [3] => FZ 36(S) (2 x 6 x 3MH)
  w/p (3+3)
        [7] => 1 SET
        [8] => 121,232.00
        [10] => 121,232.00
    )

  [7] => Array
    (
        [8] => Total in QAR
        [10] => 511,429.00
    )
)
```

this type of array I have got from excel sheet which I have read.

and my function is:

```
public function searchForId($array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if (in_array('S/NO', $val)) {
           return $key;
       }
   }
   return null;
}
```

where I am doing wrong please help me.Thank You in advance!!

Comment: is $val the above array?

Comment: You are not using `in_array` properly.

Comment: @Ekin Yes, $val is the above array

Comment: @Bizley Can you elaborate your answer?

Comment: @S.Mayuri if the example array is passed to `searchForId` as `$array` then `$val` is not an array but a string - and `in_array` needs array as second parameter.

Comment: @Bizley $val contains above array not a string.

Comment: @Bizley $array contains Array ( [2] => PRICE: ) 
Array ( [1] => S/NO [3] => INSULATED TANK SIZE [7] => QTY [8] => U.PRICE(Qr.) [10] => TOTAL PRICE (Qr.) ) 
Array ( [1] => 01 [3] => FH-9(S) (3 x 2 x 1.5MH) [7] => 1 SET [8] => 44,867.00 [10] => 44,867.00 )

Comment: Can you post a full example of an `$array` you would pass in? From what I can make out `$array` is a multidimensional array?

Comment: @Brett, I have edited my question could you check that please.

Answer (score 2):

Change your if statement as

```
 if (in_array('S/NO', $val)) {
```

Well, the most reliable would to use [`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) which would eliminate your whole function -

```
$key = array_search('S/NO', $array); //will return 1 for S/No and 7 for QTY.
```

Write array search inside your searchForId() function or try by trimming the values of array like shown above.

Comment: I have also used array_search() function but still not working

Comment: use it in the place where you are calling `searchForId()`. Can you post the code where it is being called ?

Comment: Yes sure,following is the code where searchForId() function called

Comment: //Getting data from excel sheet
 public function getData($last_id){
  
  $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("Test1.xls");
  $cell_data = $data->sheets[1]['cells'];
  $id = $this->searchForId('S/NO', $cell_data);
  $key = $id + 1;
  echo "key=".$key;die;
  while(count($cell_data[$key]) == 5) {
   $this->insertData($cell_data[$key++],$last_id);
  } 
 }

 //Getting id of S/NO
 public function searchForId($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
        if (in_array('S/NO', $val)) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return null;
 }

Comment: You can't use `trim` on an `array`; not sure why you would anyway unless you wanted to run it over all the values within it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me you just need to do:

```
<?php
$array = [
    "S/NO",
    "INSULATED TANK SIZE",
    "QTY",
    "U.PRICE(Qr.)",
    "TOTAL PRICE (Qr.)"
];

public function searchForId($array) {
    $key = array_search('S/NO', $array);
    return $key;
}

var_dump(searchForId($array));
```

Results [here](https://3v4l.org/YORHj).

[array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) returns you the key already, or false if value is not found. Using in_array you won't directly get the key, if that's your aim. You could check if the return value is false|null at the place you call this function. I would do `return $key ?? null`(php 7+)

**UPDATE**

Here's how you can do with the last array you have given. Also see [here](https://3v4l.org/NIQ2V).

```
public function searchForId($array) {
    foreach($array as $k => $sub){
        $key = array_search('S/NO', $sub);
        if($key !== false){
           return $key; 
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

var_dump(searchForId($array));
```

Since the $key is int(0), and in all other cases you get bool(false) from array_search, you should check whether the $key is literally false and if so, continue to the next array :-)

Comment: but this is not working for my array which I have got.Can you suggest me for above mentioned array?

Comment: sure, but it's super unreadable, could you please update your question with the array written as I did for you @S.Mayuri? or paste a clear var_dump in your question

Comment: ... cause I see three arrays there on that comment @S.Mayuri

Comment: I have got this type of array from excel sheet

Comment: can I use array_search() function for above mentioned array

Comment: yes, read the update carefully and check the https://3v4l.org/NIQ2V where I used your array @S.Mayuri